# Module: When should I mention the required Perl version in the documentation?

Tags: perl, documentation, version

Which one is the highest Perl version which I would not mention anymore as a requirement in a documentation?
For example I've never seen: Needs Perl 4 or higher.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ultimately, there is no harm in providing extra information to the user, so if you know of incompatibility with even a very old version, you might as well mention it.

Perl 4 is considered a separate language, however.  There is no need to mention that;  no one would expect a C++ program to run in C.

Judging from people's questions on this forum, 5.8 is still in widespread use.  So if you are interested in making a module that is well-tested and as widely useful as possible, I think it would be a good idea to at least go back that far with your testing.

If you need a certain version to run, using [`require VERSION`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) within your module could be helpful to enforce this requirement.  That way, the user gets a clear error message if they try to run your module on a version that is too old.

Comment: I agree with "it doesn't hurt to say what you require", and I may be an old fart, but I would lean towards mentioning any requirement that's >5.6.1 (i.e. if your code works on 5.8 but not 5.6, you mention that). That said, the oldest version I would expect anyone to write new code for would be 5.8.3.

Comment: [*Stack Overflow* is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).

Answer (score 4):

Document the oldest Perl you actually test with, whatever that may be.  Don't guess at it; incompatibilities creep in. As mentioned by others, declare your minimum version both in your code with a `use v5.x` and in your module meta-data.

How far back should you go? Whatever the oldest version you're willing to support and test. It's your time and potential frustration. The further back you go the more features you miss out on, the fewer CPAN modules work, and the more bugs you have to work around.

If you're using threads or Unicode, use the latest you possibly can.  Unicode support is always being improved. Threads started off very buggy in 5.8, began to firm up in 5.10 and have gotten better since.

5.10.1 is a very safe minimum and you get things like [autodie, parent, compression and archive modules, defined-or, say, given/when, smart match and named captures](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.0/perldelta.html). 5.10.1 in particular because [it fixes how smart match works in ways incompatible with 5.10.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.1/perldelta.html#Smart-match-changes). It's [what comes with Debian stable](http://packages.debian.org/stable/perl-base), which is a good lower bar for compatibility. This is the earliest you can expect reliable support from most CPAN modules.

The next step before that is 5.8.9, the last in the 5.8 series.  This is the oldest Perl you're likely to see in anything like a sane production environment. You lose a lot of features, threads are unlikely to work very well, Unicode is still a bit shaky, and CPAN modules start to break.

Before that is 5.8.4 which is the oldest Perl known to ship with a mainstream operating system, Solaris. Here's a [handy list of operating system versions and what Perl they shipped with](https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/versions).

Before that is 5.6.1. 5.6.2, while containing many bug fixes, was never widely adopted. At this point you're several layers deep in crusty, dusty installs which are never going to upgrade. Threads and Unicode support exists, but in very different and very broken forms. Many CPAN modules do not support 5.6.

5.005_03 and 5.004_04 are the next crumbling ledge. At this point is becomes masochism or an academic exercise. You might find a few very old installs kicking around, or a few "Perl was better before they added threads and Unicode" die hards.

Anything before 5.004 and very common pieces of syntax, like `foreach my $foo` are not available.

Comment: +1 for lots of interesting information on previous versions.

Answer (score 3):

www.perl.org:

> Current version: Perl 5.16.1

So maybe anything above 5.10 would be nice to mention.

I use Modern::Perl

> SYNOPSIS
>
> Modern Perl programs use several modules to enable additional features of Perl and of the CPAN. Instead of copying and pasting all of these use lines, instead write only one:

```
use Modern::Perl
```

> For forward compatibility, I recommend you specify a year as the single optional import tag. For  example:
>   use Modern::Perl '2009';
>   use Modern::Perl '2010';
>
> ... both enable 5.10 features, ...

***see also:***
perldoc Modern::Perl or https://metacpan.org/module/Modern::Perl

Comment: Or even anything above 5.8, I saw this version often enough on production servers.

Answer (score 2):

If you know a minimum version is required, why not document it? Dependencies are usually documented in the README file and specified to the installer in Makefile.PL or Build.PL.

5.14 and 5.16 are the only two supported versions of Perl, but many still use 5.8 and 5.10. I even hear about 5.5 and 5.6 on occasion.

Comment: Supported by who? Only the latest stable is likely to get official bugfix releases. [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) supports 5.14 and 5.16 for free and will sell support for older versions. What really matters is what CPAN modules support.

Comment: @Schwern, Perl5 Porters. And no, the latest *two* stable releases get bugfix releases. (e.g. Perl 5.14.3 came out a few days ago.)

Comment: Ooh, I didn't see they actually did another 5.14 release!